# Node.js copy hidden folder recursively while preserving hidden status

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, copy, hidden-files

I have tried several NPM packages, like,

```
const ncp = require("ncp").ncp
await ncp(source, destination)
```

and,

```
const fs = require("fs-extra")
fs.copySync(source, destination)
```

Both successfully copy a directory but does not preserve "hidden". For example copying ".git" yields:

[image]

Subdirectories are not hidden as well:

[image]

#### How do I recursively copy a directory while preserving existing hidden status?

Comment: Is this on Windows? And only on windows?

Comment: @Matt I have not tested on Linux yet. So far it happens in Windows.